# packery / isotope grid not rearranging as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, masonry, packery

I've been playing about with masonry, isotope and packery for several hours and cannot for the life of me get it to work as expected.

My aim to create a grid of posts, the posts can be of either two widths, 25% or 50% of the parent container.  The width is of a post is generated randomly server side.  However, there are cases when the first row contain a large gap, where a post could fit  To illustrate this better I've put together a fiddle

The HTML

```
<div id="container" class="packery" style="width: 100%">
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
<div class="item w" style="background-color:#aaa;"></div>
<div class="item w2" style="background-color:#ff0000; width:25%;"></div>
<div class="item w" style="background-color:#00ff00; width:50%;"></div>
<div class="item w" style="background-color:#affaff; width:50%;"></div>
```

The JS

```
docReady( function() {
var $container = jQuery('#container');
$container.packery({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  scolumnWidth : ".grid_sizer"
});
```

});

and a complete fiddle of what i'm trying 
http://jsfiddle.net/nLqu015m/

In the case above I would expect packery to rearrange the elements so that the red element was the last item, s there are no unsightly gaps in the rows before the last.

I've also tried to achieve the same in Isotope but facing the same issue.

Am I missing something obvious or am I misunderstanding the purpose of Packary and Isotope?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working in your fiddle since you have not loaded isotope.